# How to make cpplint check for 4-space indentation instead of 2-space indentation?

Tags: c++, cpplint

I wrote some C++ programs where I used 2-space indent instead of 4-space indent at times, but cpplint is not warning me about these lines because it seems to be checking for 2-space indent by default (and I assume it is treating 4-space indent as two 2-space indents).

When I indented a line with 1 space, `cpplint` says:

> Weird number of spaces at line-start. Are you using a 2-space indent?  [whitespace/indent] [3]

How can I make `cpplint` check that I am using 4-space indent in my program?

Comment: Unfortunately, `cpplint` does not let you configure the number of spaces. See  [cpplint.py](https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint/blob/851ceb00cba6301b00167cf5c313532bc05cf1eb/cpplint.py#L4599) for implementation details of that check.